# Emulator refuses to boot past Android screen

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am currently a QA intern at an app publisher and I use the AVD to test apps on various Android platforms and hardware builds. I touch nothing else within the Android SDK, just launch the android exec through the terminal and go from there.

I installed and started using AVDs with no issue about a month ago, installed the Intel HAXM with no issue, etc. It randomly stopped working for me about two weeks ago and I've been struggling with it since then. I've deleted everything from the Android SDK and reinstalled several times, tried using adb to no avail, nothing. I haven't been using Eclipse to get to the AVD Manager, but even when I do it makes no difference.

I've run into a dead end after trying every potential solution I could find on the Internet. Help me before I go insane.

Also using a Retina MacBook Pro, not that I think that'd make a difference, but just incase.

Comment: The apps you test need to run on ARM emulator? If not you can try genymotion, I find this the best emulators for Android (when you don't need to test ARM process).

Comment: There *were* some issues in the past with the emulator and the retina macbooks, you might want to do a search on that and see what the current status is (though that wouldn't obviously explain why it once worked and later quit)

Comment: The emulator should however give you adb access by the time it is at the Android screen (if that is the screen it shows during its runtime startup, after booting linux).  If not, it is also possible to get  console output using emulator command line options.  It sounds like you deleted and recreated your avd, but you might want to make sure - perhaps explicitly do that without reinstalling the SDK, so that you actually get to see a screen where you have no avds to choose from.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to put this up as an answer just because I really found it to be the best solution to all of my native AVD issues (my default AVD emulators would creep even on my faster machines). I downloaded genymotion and must say that I am a million times happier with the emulation. It is faster, smoother, has more options, it just makes the native AVD look even worse than it already does on its own. Even if genymotion isn't for you, I highly recommend looking into third party emulators. It will make QA, development, etc. with Android that much easier. Assuming ARM isn't required (don't think it does ARM emulation)